# Multiple toggle buttons, 1 jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, this

Trying to work out if it's possible to have multiple toggle buttons on my page while not having to repeat jQuery .toggleClass code for each button (with different id's)? Maybe use 'this' or some other method?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").toggle('fast');
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<button>Toggle</button>

<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
<p>This is another small paragraph.</p>
  
<button>Toggle</button>

<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
<p>This is another small paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you opposed to adding extra HTML for your solution? i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/86gw6a2j/

Comment: No, that's awesome @BuddhistBeast . That fixes most of my page.  What about the close button I have at the bottom of each info box?
I've updated the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/86gw6a2j/1/

Comment: Will the close button just close the box as well? Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/86gw6a2j/2/)

Comment: Close @BuddhistBeast . The close button also needs to be hidden when clicked

Comment: Looks like your jQuery syntax was just a bit off, try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/86gw6a2j/3/)

Answer (score 0):

to toggle the next p you need to use .next()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(this).next('p').fadeToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

to toggle the next p and next next p you need to use .next()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $(this).next('p').fadeToggle('fast');
            $(this).next().next().fadeToggle('fast');
        });
    });
```

you can select your button ids like

```
 $("#button1, #button2").click();
```

I don't prefer your html structure .. if you can put each button and its P in one div  it will be better to handle

Answer (score 0):

You can use event delegation.

For example, if you bind click event to buttons. I think you can use **id or data** attribute to differentiate which button is triggered. Then you can move forward.

Answer (score 0):

$(function() {
                    $('#toggle-event1,#toggle-event2,#toggle-event3,#toggle-event4,#toggle-event5').change(function() {
                       let state1 = $(this).prop('checked');
                       //alert( "First handler for .toggle() called." );

```
                  alert(this.id);})
```